# Fuzzy logic on price calculation

Tags: c#-4.0

I am having one price calculation code in C#.There is particular sequence of calculating all the prices and taxes.how to apply fuzzy logic so that I will get related search of that particular price.That means if one of tax name is 'cost/kg'.So I should get all the names of taxes or prices which start from C or CO.

Comment: this question is very vague, perhaps show something you have tried, some sample data and required output etc.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would be getting prices within some min/max bounds of what has been searched

```
double k = 0.1;
double min = searchedAmount - (searchedAmount * k);
double max = searchedAmount + (searchedAmount * k);

var results = products.Where(p => p.Price >= min && p.Price <= max);
```